# Truffle test doesn't recognize estimateGas function

Tags: truffle, truffle-test, gas-estimate, test

I'm trying to test my contracts using Truffle and Ganache, but I'm facing some problems with some functions. When I call a non view function, I'm getting the error "out of gas". Moreover, if I try to use the "estimateGas" function to check how much gas is spent on that transaction, the function isn't recognized and the console says that "estimateGas is not a function" even where, if I log my contract function, it clearly says that estimateGas exists.

I'm leaving here the code I'm using in the Javascript test file.

```
const MyContract= artifacts.require("MyContract");

contract("MyContract", (accounts) => {
  it("should construct correctly", async () => {
    let users = [
      "0x62CeeD6A2e86f1a4bA54cc7E9C1C1d61E229109a",
      "0xaFdB5c9612c0961Bb7f577202F5888d009ca84B0",
      "0x62CeeD6A2e86f1a4bA54cc7E9C1C1d61E229109a",
    ];
    let names = ["Jack", "Mark", "Jack"];
    let ids = [1, 2, 3];

    const instance = await MyContract.deployed();
    console.log(instance.fillUser.estimateGas); // This log says that estimateGas is a function
    instance
      .fillUser(users, names, ids)
      .estimateGas({ from: accounts[0], gasPrice: 20000000000 }, function (
        error,
        gasAmount
      ) {
        console.log(Number(gasAmount));
      }); // This fails because estimateGas is not recognized as a function
  });
});
```

Comment: Try `.fillUser.estimateGas(users, names, ids, { from: ...})`.

Comment: BTW, you don't need to pass `gasPrice` to it (and you do need to pass `value`, if the function is `payable`).

Comment: @goodvibration it's not payable, it's just not a view-only function, it changes some logic in smart contract (changes mapping values)

Comment: That was a 'BTW' comment. Have you tried my initial suggestion?

Comment: @goodvibration I tried it right now, it doesn't give the error anymore but it doesn't log anything either, the gasAmount is not shown in the console

Comment: To begin with, since you are passing an `async` function to this `it`, why don't you simply use `await` everywhere (rather than callback functions)?

Comment: For example: `const gasAmount = await instance.fillUser.estimateGas(users, names, ids), { from: accounts[0] });`. If you want to handle errors as well, then put this inside a try/catch block.

Comment: @goodvibration Using the async function at least I get a different error, that is again the "out of gas" error. I set the gasLimit and the gasPrice shown in Ganache into both the truffle-config and the last parameter of the function, and I even set the solc optimizer in the truffle config. I don't understand what the problem is

Comment: Gas-Price has nothing to do with `out of gas`. The contract function probably reverts on the given input, so `estimateGas` cannot estimate the gas required for it. You haven't share your contract code, so it's hard to say for sure.

Comment: @goodvibration The function fillUser takes in input three parameters: an array of addresses, an array of strings and an array of uint256. I had to use the experimental ABI Encoder v2 for this to work because of the array of strings that's not supported by the default encoder. Could this be the problem?

Comment: The problem is mostly likely not in the parameters that the function takes, but in what it does with them (or with what it does in general). Again, you have not provided the relevant code, so it's hard to analyze further.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118147/discussion-between-sosnos-and-goodvibration).

Answer (score 0):

It is called wrongfully. It should be:

```js
const instance = await MyContract.deployed();
const gasCost = await instance.fillUser.estimateGas(users, names, ids, { 
    from: accounts[0], 
    gasPrice: 20000000000 
})
```

Note the parameters are passed to `estimateGas` not to the contract function `fillUser`